# error messages are displaying different in both eclipse and command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse

Sub: error messages are displaying different in both eclipse and command prompt

```
//DataHidingDemo program
class Bank {
private static double balance = 1000;// Data Hiding
}

public class DataHidingDemo extends Bank {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Balance:" + balance);
}}
```

**Case 1:**

run the program from eclipse and observe below error message is displaying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The field Bank.balance is not visible
at oops.DataHidingDemo.main(DataHidingDemo.java:10)
```

**Case 2:**
run the same program from command prompt and observe below error message is displaying
D:\Java Programs_CMD>javac DataHidingDemo.java

```
DataHidingDemo.java:10: error: balance has private access in Bank
            System.out.println("Balance:"+balance);
                                          ^
```

1 error

**Observe both case 1 & 2 error messages; case 2 error message has meaningful.**

Q).Do we have the way to display the same error message in eclipse too? (for this do we need to change any setting in eclipse) please help on this.

Comment: You should be getting an error indicator in the editor, the packages view and the problems view.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has its own Java compiler, which is thus different from javac, and thus generates different error messages. AFAIK, no, it's not possible to make Eclipse use the javac compiler. Both NetBeans and IntelliJ IDEA use javac, though, so you might want to try thise IDEs instead.

Note that the error you got from Eclipse is a message generated when you tried **running** code that did not compile. Don't do that. If there are compilation errors listed, then fix them all before running. The compilation errors are listed in the "Problems" view and in the "Markers" view of Eclipse.